# How to implement a collapse feature for long content in table cells like HuggingFace?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

When table content exceeds two lines, it:

- is collapsed by default
- expands upon clicking
- collapses again when clicking outside the table

Example: [fka/awesome-chatgpt-prompts · Datasets at Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/datasets/fka/awesome-chatgpt-prompts)

[image: example of such a table]

Based on reverse engineering, the "collapsed" feature is implemented by CSS like this:

```css
.line-clamp {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.line-clamp-2 {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

However, I have no idea about the others - it seems a `focus` event, but it is useless when I add focus like (click works instead) :

```js
const change = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    if (target.getAttribute("class") === 'fold') {
        target.setAttribute("class", "fold line-clamp-2");
    } else {
        target.setAttribute("class", "fold");
    }
    console.log(target);
}

const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.fold.line-clamp-2');
for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', change);
    cells[i].addEventListener('focus', change);
}
```

```css
.fold {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.line-clamp-2 {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="fold line-clamp-2">
        Row 1, Column 1
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="fold line-clamp-2">
        Row 1, Column 2
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="fold line-clamp-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed malesuada, magna in bibendum viverra, ex odio semper 
        velit, vel placerat erat ipsum eget nibh. Aliquam erat 
        volutpat. Nam vel laoreet nisl. Nulla euismod ex vel 
        dapibus dictum. Aliquam quis mauris leo. Sed bibendum 
        metus et ex euismod, a faucibus libero elementum. Donec 
        commodo purus ante, in placerat diam elementum quis. 
        Integer auctor, magna non sollicitudin dictum, sapien 
        quam suscipit nunc, in tempor orci quam ut ipsum. 
        Maecenas euismod pellentesque orci, quis congue nisi 
        malesuada ac. Proin id tincidunt tellus. 
        <br><br>
        Donec velit velit, tempor vel mauris vel, vestibulum 
        malesuada orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam 
        elementum dictum erat eu faucibus. In varius augue 
        ut metus auctor congue. Quisque pharetra, erat ut 
        consectetur bibendum, erat sem tincidunt odio, ac 
        feugiat purus risus et diam. Nam a elit in lectus 
        tempor congue. Donec fringilla nisi non libero 
        vestibulum aliquam. Fusce quis nisl id sem laoreet 
        rutrum. 
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Tailwind `line-clamp-2 group-focus:line-clamp-none`.